# why QTextEedit can't gain focus even when i clicked it, in symbian device

Tags: c++, qt, symbian

i place a QTextEdit widget into a QWidget class(the QTextEdit's parent widget),but when the parent widget show,i clicked the QTextEdit,but it can't gain focus.how this situation comes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about symbian development so this is only a guess. Check the [focus policy](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qt.html#FocusPolicy-enum) for the text edit. You probably want `Qt::ClickFocus` or `Qt::StrongFocus`.

Comment: my solution: subclass QTextEdit,reimplement mousePressEvent(),and show a dialog,and then close it, ....The QTextEdit gain the foucs!!!